# How did John Teller actually die?

Tags: plot-explanation, sons-of-anarchy

How did John Teller actually die in *Sons of Anarchy*? Was it suicide?  No matter how many times I watch certain episodes I am unable to figure it out.

- Did Gemma/Clay sabotage the bike and John never knew it and so actually Clay/Gemma killed him before John actually wanted out.
- Did John knew they will sabotage it and was waiting for it as the most logical point to die as a way out? So clay kills the John's mechanic once John dies?
- Was John by then too far gone to make sense of anything and just plainly tries to ride away from the club with his bike and he meets with an accident? (Gemma/Clay is yet to put their plans into action, The mechanic John teller trusts, is still loyal to John, never sabotages the bike and chooses to disappear rather than face Clay? Because if what Jury says is true, and john did not yet want out dead, as soon as he would start a bike he would know, why did he ride out so far. Gemma also says sometime that they put John back together but he is unraveling again. Gemma/Clay mistakenly think they succeeded in killing him.)

  - This is because Jury tells Jax just before he dies S07 EP08 that John
    wanted out and it's his sacrifice. If Clay/Gemma sabotaged the bike,
    he would have known it.
  - That also does not make sense of something - If he wanted himself dead, how would that help the club? Clay could go on to make a bigger mess of what he is currently doing now.

If John knew then below may support it:

- Before his death does he believe Clay would see the error of his
  ways and lead the MC into a better future influenced by his friend's
  death and Jack's adoption as a son?
- I remember the scene where Clay (possibly) lovingly sees Jack's son in incubator. That would make him his adopted grandfather?
- True to his character, Clay leads the club well for the next few years, sees through many of his decisions and the MC is stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, Clay revealed that he tried to murder JT twice before his fatal accident.  After Clay started his affair with Gemma, they conspired to get JT out of the picture by tampering with his brakes.  JT supposedly knew what was going on and let it happen, believing it was his only way out of the club and being completely disenchanted with what he created.  In effect, he committed suicide.  Similarly, Jax ended his life more or less the same way, becoming equally disenchanted with the direction he forced the club.

Comment: Then Clay/Gemma knew that John knew and he wanted out ? does he write that blue wordings on the hill before he dies ... Guess his brakes were good then. Also why does he keep writing to his Irish wife, it sounded to me like he doesn't wanna die and is afraid of Clay and Gemma